# Proving $\lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{r^{\frac{3}{2}}(\ln r +1)^2}{r^2-1} = 0$

Tags: limits

What is the shortest (or most *elegant*) way to prove:

$$\lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{r^{\frac{3}{2}}(\ln r +1)^2}{r^2-1} = 0$$

I've tried writing it as 
$$\lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac{(\ln r +1)^2}{r^{\frac{1}{2}}-r^{-\frac{3}{2}}}$$
and then using L'Hospital rule. Which seems to be working. (after using L'Hospital twice)

Is there a more elegant (or shorter) way to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is $0$ iff the numerator goes to $0$.

FOILing it out you get:

$$r^{3/2}(\ln^2 r+2\ln r+1)$$

which goes to $0$ iff $r^{3/2}\ln^2 r$ does by using the squeeze theorem and the fact that

$$0 \le r^{3/2}(\ln r+1)^2\le 2r^{3/2}\ln^2 r$$

The RHS goes to zero iff $2(r^{3/4}\ln r)^2$ does, i.e. iff $r^{3/4}\ln r$ does.

Here we finally write this as a ratio:

$$\lim_{r\to 0^+} {\ln r\over r^{-3/4}}=-{4\over 3}\lim_{\to 0^+}{r^{-1}\over r^{-7/4}}$$

$$=-{4\over 3}\lim_{r\to 0^+}r^{3/4}=0$$

Comment: That's nice. Two little questions: 1) "...which goes to 0 iff $r^{\frac{3}{2}}\ln^2 r$ does...". Shouldn't it be proved analogous that $r^{\frac{3}{2}}\cdot 3\ln r$ heads of to zero? 2) Why can you state $(\ln r+ 1)^2 \leqslant 2\ln^2 r$? I would argument $(\ln r+ 1)^2 \leqslant \ln^2 r$ (without 2) if $r \to 0$ since $\ln r \leqslant \ln r +1 \leqslant 0 $ if $r \to 0$.

Comment: @dietervdf 2) No, if you FOIL out $(\ln r+1)2$ you get $\ln^2r+2\ln r+1$ and clearly $\ln^2r\ge 2\ln r+1$ since the LHS is positive and the RHS is not.

1) Because of the squeeze theorem bounds that are right after that statement.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. 1) I understand the argument you provide. Would the argument I stated also be valid? 2) You use the squeeze theorem to prove $r^{3/2}\ln^2 r\to 0$. But in the line above, should It also be proved $2 r^{3/2}\ln r \to 0$? Else you'd get something of the form "$0 + (-\infty) + 0$"?

Comment: @dietervdf 1) I suppose if you want to also prove $r^{3/2}\ln r\to 0$, that's not wrong, it's just a bit longer.
2) As I said in (1), I use the squeeze theorem so that I don't have to do both terms separately (I'm lazy) but if you want to, you are fine proving each term goes to $0$ then summing them, that's totally legitimate.

Comment: I see it now, thanks!